# Naming convention for filter class?

Tags: refactoring, naming-conventions

I wonder how could this be named better.

I've have class `Filter` (it happens to be in Ruby, but the language isn't all that important), which filters objects just like this:

```
class Filter
    def initialize(items)
        @items = items
    end

    def filter
        #returns filtered items
    end
end
```

In use it looks like this:

```
items = Filter.filter
```

I don't like it. Does anyone have any other *better* construction for this?

Comment: It's `Filter.filter` and if this doesn't get closed them I'm interested in the answers... naming things is always the most difficult part of coding.

Comment: language doesn't matter its about convention.. but, its ruby

Comment: I think I have at times used Filter for the class and in() for the method.  Filter.in() and Filter.out().

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly clear that plain `Filter` co-opts to this one class a name that could reasonably be used by many classes that do parallel but distinct jobs.

If you can parameterize the selection criterion (preferably in the initialization function so that you don't store items that won't be returned), then you could call this `Filter`.  If you can't parameterize it, then you should be using a more specific name such as `BrokenWidgetsFilter` (if the filter picks out the broken widgets presented to it).